# Add page template located in a custom wordpress plugin into page attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, plugins

Is it possible to add a page template located in a wordpress plugin folder instead of the theme folder so it is showing in the page attributes?

For a single page and archive i am using this code:

```
if ( get_post_type() == 'register' ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-register.php' ) ) ) {
            $template_path = $theme_file;
        } else {
            $template_path = CONDOREG__PLUGIN_DIR . '/single-register.php';
        }
    }
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'archive-condoleances.php' ) ) ) {
            $template_path = $theme_file;
        } else {
            $template_path = CONDOREG__PLUGIN_DIR . '/archive-condoleances.php';
        }
    }

}
return $template_path;
```

But for now it is not showing up in the attributes?